# If something is rigidly attached to a vibrating part, does the number of contact points effect the vibration transfer?

Tags: vibrations

I have an enclosure mounted to the chassis of a vehicle. There are multiple points where the enclosure is fastened to the chassis as well as areas where it rests on the chassis without being fastened. Is there any point in putting vibration pads on the areas where the enclosure rests on the chassis? Logically I feel like anything fastened rigidly to the chassis would vibrate the same as the chassis.